# Generate dynamic route path in asp.net core

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created one .net core application that has below path for crud operations.

Create: `http://localhost:1001/admin/123/app/456/user/Create`

Update: `http://localhost:1001/admin/123/app/456/user/Update`

Select: `http://localhost:1001/admin/123/app/456/user/Select`

Writing below will solve the issue in the URL.

```
routes.MapRoute("CreateUser", "apps/{appId}/user/create",
  defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Create" });
```

How to include the same in .cshtml file i.e
 `<a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="User"> Create User </a>`

The quick help appreciated.

Comment: How to include what? Do you mean `{appId}` part of the URL?

Comment: yes , the url should be `http://localhost:1001/admin/{adminID}/app/{appId}/user/Select` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asp-route-{value}` option to indicate route values in anchor tag helper:

```
<a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="User" asp-route-adminID="@Model.AdminId" asp-route-appId="@Model.AppId"> Create User </a>
```

Please consider that I assumed that `adminId` and `appId` values are provided in the Model of the page. If it's wrong, set appropriate variable instead of those in your code.

For more information, you can check the Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.0#asp-route-value